# nginx server_name not servicing requests

Tags: nginx, certbot

Under `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`  two configuration files exist and return
`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful` when invoking `nginx -t`

```
default  misa
```

However each of the server_name entries of the misa configuration (follows) is being redirected to the site that is configured as default: **note: the server_name list is actually much longer**

```
server {
   server_name       misa.iwant2go2.com,misaimpianti.com,www.misaimpianti.com;
   passenger_enabled on;
   rails_env         production;
   root              /home/deploy/websaim/current/public;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
      root html;
    }


listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/misa.iwant2go2.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/misa.iwant2go2.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    listen 80;
   server_name       o3-technology.net,www.o3-technology.net,ozone-technology.eu;
   passenger_enabled on;
   rails_env         production;
   root              /home/deploy/webmisa/current/public;
}
```

I am not certain whether this behaviour appeared after installing certificates via Certbot (there were problems in issuing certificates due to the length of the string being submitted), requiring `nginx.conf` to be configured as follows:

```
server_names_hash_bucket_size 512;
```

(the server will not pass the test if set at less than `256`)

Another interesting observation is that, in the second block, the first two domains listed only as a listen-port-80  has nginx returning a `404` error when that domain is submitted, while the last one is being re-directed to the default configuration.

Thus it appears that this entire configuration file is being ignored by nginx somewhere. *tested also with a single block on port 80, no reference to certificates, and the domains are pointing at default setting*

Where/how can this be resolved?  Should I also consider removing the certificates, uninstalling Certbot to try first unencrypted (before re-installing and issuing certificates)?

Comment: Did you run `nginx -T` to see if the active configuration has the information you expect to see?

Comment: capital 't' ?  I was not aware of that function...